# Distorsión audio - omxplayer - raspberry pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi

Estoy trabajando con el omxplayer - raspberry pi 3

```
omxplayer -o hdmi --loop --no-osd --win "0 0 1920 1080" files/media/1ac572e4ec86f1f4c4161ce6d46ca5ca.mp4 < /tmp/omx-control
```

Empieza en 0.00dB

Pero cuando le subo el volumen por comando:

```
echo -n "+" > /tmp/omx-control
```

sube a 3.00dB
6.00dB
Hasta aquí se escucha bien pero al siguiente empieza a distorsionarse el sonido, como si hubiera interferencia.
9.00dB
Y ni que decir si le sigo enviando el comando de +, empieza a sonar mucho peor.

Alguien sabe a qué se debe y cómo podría resolverlo?

Gracias!

Answer (score 4):

### ¿A qué se debe?

Estás subiendo el audio digitalmente y no analógicamente. Al querer subir el volumen y encontrarte que ya emite el valor más grande posible, sólo sería válida la distorsión:
[image: Aquí muestro la imagen de la distorsión]

Como resultado, obtendrás, siempre que la señal que quieras reproducir esté en el máximo de reproducción, una distorsión como la que estás viendo justo encima.

### ¿Cómo soluciono esto?

Amplificando la señal de forma externa con un equipo de música. De esa forma aumentarás el volumen. No podrías hacerlo internamente, pero gracias a la versatilidad de la Raspberry Pi, sí puedes utilizar amplificadores de audio conectados digitalmente a la placa, pero es hardware externo, remarco.

Comment: Hola! Gracias por tu respuesta. En realidad, solo dispongo de un TV que está conectado a la raspberry pi 3 via HDMI. El volumen lo controlo a través de una webapp hecha en angularjs. Cuando hago click al botón " + " lo que hace es enviar el comando + del omxplayer.

Comment: Ok, lo resolví de la siguiente mantera, cuando levanto el video, lo hago con el flag de --vol -5000 y con el volumen maximo del televisor

Comment: Es decir, tienes amplificado al máximo que te permite el dispositivo de escucha, el volumen de forma analógica, y de forma digital controlas la ganancia de tu audio en la raspi, antes de que salga hacia el dispositivo de escucha. Posiblemente ahora percibas que con volúmenes muy bajos escuches ruido de cuantización (es similar a los sonidos de una gameboy)

Comment: @imendivil, si te fue de ayuda esta respuesta, podrías marcarla como válida.